# $L^p$-norm of a Standard gaussian random variable

Tags: calculus, probability, normed-spaces, normal-distribution

I need some help in solving this exercise.

I have computed, basically with a change of variables, that:
\begin{equation}
E(|X|^p)^{1/p}=\sqrt{2}\bigg(\dfrac{\Gamma((p+1)/2)}{\Gamma(1/2)}\bigg)^{1/p}
\end{equation}

Can someone give me some hint in order to show that:
\begin{equation}
E(|X|^p)^{1/p}=\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{p})
\end{equation}

EDIT

Using Stirling's approximation for $\Gamma(x)\approx\bigg(\dfrac{x}{e}\bigg)^x\sqrt{\dfrac{2\pi}{x}}$ we have:
\begin{equation}
\Gamma\bigg(\dfrac{p+1}{2}\bigg)\approx\bigg(\dfrac{p+1}{2e}\bigg)^{(p+1)/2}\sqrt{\dfrac{4\pi}{p+1}}=2^{(1-p)/2}e^{-(p+1)/2}(p+1)^{p/2}\sqrt{\pi}
\end{equation}

Using now this and simplifying $\sqrt{\pi}$ with $\Gamma(1/2)$ we get:
\begin{equation}
E(|X|^p)^{1/p}=\sqrt{2}\bigg(\dfrac{\Gamma((p+1)/2)}{\Gamma(1/2)}\bigg)^{1/p}\approx\sqrt{2}\cdot2^{(1-p)/2p}\cdot e^{-(p+1)/2p}(p+1)^{1/2}
\end{equation}
finally since $\lim_{p\to\infty}\sqrt{2}\cdot2^{(1-p)/2p}\cdot e^{-(p+1)/2p}=C$ for some constant $C$ we can conclude that $E(|X|^p)^{1/p}=\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{p})$ as $p\to\infty$

Comment: My first guess would be Stirling?

Comment: So I write $\Gamma((p+1)/2)$ as $((p+1)/2)!$ and than I approximate it with stirling?

Comment: @Pefok yes Stirling gives $\Gamma(p/2)\approx(\frac p{2\mathrm e})^{p/2}$ so $\Gamma(p/2)^{1/p}\approx(\frac p{2\mathrm e})^{1/2}=\mathcal O(\sqrt p)$. (Of course you have to make this rigorous.)

Comment: @nejimban I tried to make your idea more rigorous, is it ok?

Comment: @Pefok: It is fine but I find it more rigorous to write $\Gamma(x)=\left(\frac xe\right)^{\!x}\sqrt\frac{2\pi}x\left(1+O\!\left(\frac1x\right)\!\right)$ instead of $\Gamma(x)\approx\left(\frac xe\right)^{\!x}\sqrt\frac{2\pi}x$ (and similarly for $\Gamma(\frac{p+1}2)$).

Comment: Ok thank you so much

Comment: Consider answering your own question, so this doesn't remain under unanswered questions, now that you have figured it out.